# Should I use UUID or regular auto_increment for my userIDs?

Tags: mysql, json, security, jwt, uuid

I am building an application with a node.js backend in combination with MySQL. In the database, I have a table "users" which contains the information about a user. Currently, those have regular id's with a primary key - so my user IDs are 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

The issue I am now facing is that I use a JSON Web Token to authenticate the user and store the userID in the payload. For example, my payload looks like this:

```
userID: 173
userName: PennyWise
userLevel: user
```

I am now wondering if I should change my userIDs to UUIDs. I read that this might slow down on inserts, but this would only happen when a new user signs up so I don't think it should be that big of an issue (it's not like a table filled with posts which have 100s of inserts on a daily basis).

The reason why I would like to do this, is because if a JWT gets compromised and the secret to sign it is also compromised, the data could be corrupted and simply change the userID to, let's say, 122 and then that user would have access to all the data of userID 122 instead of 173.

I am not saying it will happen - I use a token valid for 21 days (mobile application) and check if the issue date is older than 3 hours to refresh it (using a refresh token), which is then checked against the database to see if it's still the same - this refresh token is automatically changed when the password is changed for which the original password is needed. But I would feel more confident I think, if the IDs are not that "obvious" to read.

Any ideas or suggestions about this? Stick with regular ID's (0, 1, 2, 3) or change to UUID's for this specific case and storing it in a JWT?

Cheers!

Comment: 1. You are probably exposing your user ids somewhere anyway, so guessing isn’t necessary to get valid user ids. 2. If your secret is compromised, you have a whole load of issues either way. 3. You can rotate your secret when you find it’s compromised.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of performance keep your user ids as autoincrementing integers. That helps performance a great deal.

For another thing, UUIDs generated on a single machine aren't hard enough to guess to qualify as secure. If you need a cryptographically secure (hard-to-guess) secret id for each user, generate one and put it in each user's row. Just don't use it as the primary key. Most host languages have a secure random number generator; MySQL doesn't.

Third, guard your JWT secrets carefully and rotate them often. Hard-to-guess and short-lived are an excellent combination. With thanks to Gary Larson, unless you work at one of the giant companies, your best approach to cybersecurity is "be more secure than the next guy."

[image: By Gary Larson]

Comment: If you generate v4 UUIDs with a library using a proper RNG, they shouldn’t be any more guessable originating from one machine.